# How to change Ubercart status messages in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

my client asked me to replace "cart" in status messages (e.g. "Item added to your shopping cart.") with the word "bag". However, I found out that all these messages are hardcoded in Ubercart module. What's the best way to change them?

Thanks.

Comment: Ubercart is open-source.  Change the status messages in the source, and recompile.  Or, if the messages are stored in a file, just change the file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is not an acceptable solution. Does not matter whether is it open source or not, the point is that the original source remains untouched (otherwise I would need to change the messages again and again, every time I let's say update the module, wouldn't I). The change needs to be done either on configuration level or via coding my own module and extend the functionality.

Comment: Didn't you just say the messages are *hardcoded* into the Ubercart module?  You might get a faster answer by asking the folks at Ubercart directly.

Comment: Yes, they are, however, Drupal has many ways of how to extend and change functionality and maybe I am missing something. Nevertheless, thanks for your comments, if I put the changes in one patch file maybe is your solution not unacceptable after all...

Answer (score 0):

This module https://drupal.org/project/messages_alter provides Drupal hook for altering status messages. This hook enables developers to alter the text that is displayed in status messages before the messages are themed.